# Paginação datatable com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery-datatables

Estou usando o DataTable para renderizar meus registros.
O problema é: Eu tenho 15 mil registros numa tabela, ele precisa carregar TODOS os registros primeiro, pra então montar o paginador.

Como eu consigo manipular isso? Carregar primeiro o limite (20), e posterior, ao ir clicando nas páginas, for buscando novos registros?

Comment: Esses registros você tem guardado em um banco de dados?

Comment: Exatamente, tenho guardados no banco de dados, eu vi exemplos que tem num jquery, mas não seria a ideia..

Comment: O que ja tentou ?

Comment: Não tentei nada, só tenho os comandos básicos da listagem... Do datatable normal,

Comment: Se eu entendi bem a pergunta, você quer fazer novos request's ao mudar de pagina, recarregando somente os registros daquela pagina atual. Pelo o que eu já pesquisei, tem sim de trazer todos os registros primeiro mesmo, pois os botões de paginação do datatable não tem um eventhandle ou callback para setar e nem na manipulação do loaded não tem uma configuração de request por ação. Aconselho fazer sua própria tabela de registros com paginação e pesquisa!

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar lhe ajuda pelo que eu entendi:

Bom, você precisará carregar o limite, que no caso você deixou claro que serão **20 registros**. Sugiro que você deixe uma div "pai" tomando conta da tabela no HTML:

```
<div id="pai">
...
</div>
```

Agora vamos aos passos do projeto:

**USANDO GET:**

**1. Crie um arquivo secundário salvo como PHP que tenha conexão com o banco de dados:**

Exemplo: pagination.php

```
<?php
    $id = (int) isset($_GET['id']) ? strip_tags($_GET['id']) : ''; // número da página atual
    $num = (int) isset($_GET['num']) ? strip_tags($_GET['num']) : ''; // número de registros por cada paginação (no seu caso foi escolhido 20)
    $total = (int) isset($_GET['total']) ? strip_tags($_GET['total']) : ''; // número total de registros
    $pages = ceil($total/$num); // número de páginas com base no número de registros e a quantidade de registro por cada paginação
    $start = ($num * $id) - $num; // calcular em que registro é começado a paginação (se você já tiver paginado uma vez (saiu da página 1 para a 2), o calculo ficaria por exemplo: [(20 * 2) - 20] = 20; onde você usará na query o start para saber de onde começam os novos registros.
?>
```

Como a query ficaria:
(usando PDO)

```
$valores = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM valores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num");
```

Após isso, você deverá listar os valores.

**USANDO POST:**

**1. Crie um arquivo secundário como PHP que tenha conexão com o banco de dados:**
Exemplo: pagination.php

```
<?php
    $id = (int) isset($_POST['id']) ? strip_tags($_POST['id']) : ''; // número da página atual
    $num = (int) isset($_POST['num']) ? strip_tags($_POST['num']) : ''; // número de registros por cada paginação (no seu caso foi escolhido 20)
    $total = (int) isset($_POST['total']) ? strip_tags($_POST['total']) : ''; // número total de registros
    $pages = ceil($total/$num); // número de páginas com base no número de registros e a quantidade de registro por cada paginação
    $start = ($num * $id) - $num; // calcular em que registro é começado a paginação (se você já tiver paginado uma vez (saiu da página 1 para a 2), o calculo ficaria por exemplo: [(20 * 2) - 20] = 20; onde você usará na query o start para saber de onde começam os novos registros.
?>
```

**2. Usando jQuery e ajax:**

Como você criou uma div pai (explicado acima), agora é necessário trocar o conteúdo dela de acordo com a troca de página.

```
var pagination = {};
pagination.currentPage = 1;
pagination.start = function(total, num, type){
    var box = $('#pai'),
        prev = $('#botao-anterior'),
        next = $('#botao-proximo'),
        calc = Number(total/num);
        /* Onde **total** será o número total de registros e **num** será o número de registros por página */
    if(type == 'next' && pagination.currentPage < calc){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pagination.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id': pagination.currentPage, 'num': num, 'total': total},
            success: function(data){
                box.html(data);
            }
        });
    } else if($type == 'prev' && pagination.currentPage > 0){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pagination.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id': pagination.currentPage, 'num': num, 'total': total},
            success: function(data){
                box.html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```